# Does $\langle u,Tu \rangle=0$ imply that $T=0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have this simple question :

> for an operator $T$ in a complex  Hilbert space we have:
>    $\langle u,Tu \rangle =0$ for all $u$ in this Hilbert space. So does this imply that $T=0$? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: Consider a rotation by $\pi/2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard inner product.

Answer (score 3):

It is true when the Hilbert space is complex. You can see this via polarization. The others showed that it is false when the field is the reals.

Comment: Friedrich Philipp   how o show that in complexe ?

Comment: See Lemma 2 here: https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/hs-1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You have $<u+v,T(u+v)>=<u,T(u)>+<u,T(v)>+<v,T(u)>+<v,T(v)>=<u,T(v)>+<v,T(u)>=0$.
Replace $v$ by $iv$, you have $<u,T(iv)>+<iv,T(u)>=-i<u,T(v)>+i<v,T(u)>$. This implies that $<u,T(v)>+<v,T(u)>=0$ and $<u,T(v)>-<v,T(u)>=0$. Thus $<v,T(u)>=0$ for every $v$. This implies $T(u)=0$.

Comment: it is a complexe hilbert space !!